# anaconda no module found insightface

Tags: pip, package, anaconda

i get an error saying no mudle found insightface and when i do pip install insightface

last output line is
building 'insightface.thirdparty.face3d.mesh.cython.mesh_core_cython' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

i have installed latest visual c++ with build tools and restarted my pc and nothing seemed to help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.